# Order of Items in GetChildren method

Tags: sitecore-api

I have Sitecore 9.3. I am using GetChildren() method to read all the children under a folder.

I tried to identify a pattern in the sequencing of items but was unable to do so.

I did saw the post at [Get all Children in the order defined in Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/get-all-children-in-the-order-defined-in-sitecore) before posting this question.

Unfortunately in my case, the response is not following the sequence as in Sitecore Content Editor.

Can someone help me to understand that?

Comment: Is it using the item sort order?

Comment: We would need to see the full code, to make any assessment. GetChildren will respect the child sort order.